# Can I use the GMAIL API to search for keywords and display related content?

Tags: gmail-api

I am wondering if I can use gmail api to search for keywords inside a message and display related content in a sidebar.

Comment: Have you had a look at the API already? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering

Answer (score 1):

Yes!! you can search any thing using query parameter in gmail api
check this link for query options

> https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

**Eg Api:**

> https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=test

this will search test in entire content, subject etc.. of email.